# install windows from cd

Tags: windows-xp, bios

I have an friends acer laptop but i don't have access to the bios, and I cannot boot from CD-ROM. Bios is password protected, my friend doesn't remember the password, and I'm too lazy to open and reset it. I have to install windows XP. What can I do?

ty

Answer (score 2):

you can't boot from the CDROM? I take it you mean becuase you can get to the BIOS you can't change the primary boot device. On most modern laptops and computer they have a quick-boot or one time boot menu that you can acess depedning on make/model by pressing one of the fuction keys (F1-F12). this should give you the change to boot from CD, Primary HD and any other bootable devices attached to the computer.

Or, reset the BIOS. It'll make your life easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a currently working windows installation, win95/98/2k/xp/vista/7, just execute the setup.exe file on the cd-rom.
The installation will proceed from there.

Comment: good idea, but this will not allow me to format the partition

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have another removable boot media, you might be out of luck unless you reset the BIOS - Even if you can run setup.exe, the first thing it does is reboot your machine and have you boot off of the CD.

If you can get the system to boot off of a USB drive, it's possible to convert a windows install disk to run off of a USB drive, but there's a good chance that clearing the BIOS would be easier and faster.